# Conversation between Lord Ram and Daṇḍakāraṇya sages exact verse

Tags: ramayana, rama, reference-request, shloka

I am trying to identify the exact verse for the conversation from **Adhyatama Ramayana** that happened between Lord Rama and Daṇḍakāraṇya sages.

Where the sages expressed their desire to become Lord Ram's wife and Lord Rama granted boon to them that, come to Gokula during my next Krishna Avatara, the verse that I have manually noted from audio lecture is as below:

> te sarve strītaṁpanā tam bhutāś ca gokula

ते सर्वे स्त्रीतंपना तम भुताश च गोकुल

does anyone know if this is the exact verse for the conversation ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's from [Krishna Upanishad](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/vedicsection/upanishads/krishna.asp#google_vignette), you can see the Sanskrit verses [here](https://cloudup.com/cg-j8GEEiqm).

> When the sages living in the forest visited Sri Ramachandra who was the incarnation of the ever joyful God Maha-Vishnu and who was extremely handsome, they became surprised and forgetting themselves said, “We want to embrace you, Oh Lord.” The God told them, “When I reincarnate as Lord Krishna, you will be born as Gopis and then you can embrace me.”[Their wish was fulfilled in Krishnavatara.] 1

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: That chat showed something wrong like you can't make any discussion in comments. So am posting the link here.

Comment: https://t.me/shaivamsadavijayate

Comment: I got the link there only actually see the chat there.

Comment: Oh, OK check there

Comment: I have already checked that telegram link from ur quora account long back.

Comment: Oh, so I don't know your telegram I'd.  what's your name there  ?

Comment: Saurav Dey......

Comment: Couldn't find you there

Comment: See, if there's any member request there.?

Comment: @SriShivaCharañamDāsaVishñu thanks, it would be very helpful to know the verse number and the exact verse as well as I might have made typo while writing the verse in the question.

Comment: @nunam see the very 1st verse itself in the Sanskrit link. Though the exact verse from question will be tricky to find there.